# Is there a way to run install4j-maven-plugin in a platform-independent fashion? (i4j 7.0.6)

Tags: maven, install4j

I was hoping that since install4j is essentially a jar file, that I could unpack the Linux/Unix `.tar.gz` and give that to `install4j-maven-plugin` via the `<installDir>` property. Sadly, this fails because the plugin insists on running a `.exe` on Windows.

Is there a way to make this work?
I could detect the environment in the POM and switch between invocation details via a Maven profile, but that would complicate the POM, so I'd greatly prefer if I could make `install4j-maven-plugin` simply run the jar file.

Relevant Maven log:

```
[INFO] --- install4j-maven-plugin:1.0.7:compile (compile-installers) @ id-gui ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=79, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=35, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=1, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=74, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=16, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=1}
[DEBUG] org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.7:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15:compile
[DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.aether:aether-api:jar:0.9.0.M3:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M3:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.4:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:1.0.7
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:1.0.7
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:1.0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.4
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:1.0.7:compile from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:1.0.7, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:1.0.7:compile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) attach = false
[DEBUG]   (f) buildSelected = false
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = false
[DEBUG]   (f) destination = C:\develop\id-gui\id-gui\target
[DEBUG]   (f) disableSigning = false
[DEBUG]   (f) failIfMissing = true
[DEBUG]   (f) faster = false
[DEBUG]   (f) installDir = C:\develop\id-gui\id-gui\target\install4j
[DEBUG]   (f) projectFile = C:\develop\id-gui\id-gui\src\install\SIX_iD.install4j
[DEBUG]   (f) quiet = false
[DEBUG]   (f) release = 10.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) test = false
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) winKeystorePassword = S3eSpuya
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.six-group.six-id:id-gui:10.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\develop\id-gui\id-gui\pom.xml
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Detected Java version: 1.8 in: C:\Daten\software\jdk-8u152-windows-x64\jre
[DEBUG] Detected OS: Windows 7
[DEBUG] Setting property: scmBranch=feature/local-installer-build
[DEBUG] Setting property: maven.build.timestamp.format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
[DEBUG] Setting property: java.version=1.8
[DEBUG] Override ignored for property "java.version"
[DEBUG] Setting property: install4j.home=C:\Daten\software\install4j7
[DEBUG] Setting property: slf4jversion=1.7.12
[DEBUG] Setting property: install4j.pass=S3eSpuya
[DEBUG] Setting property: logbackversion=0.9.24
[DEBUG] Setting property: timestamp=1529501201991
[DEBUG] Setting property: build.timestamp=2018-06-20T13:26:40
[DEBUG] Setting property: project.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
[DEBUG] Setting property: build.revision=301be02
[DEBUG] Setting property: project.basedir=C:\develop\id-gui\id-gui
[DEBUG] install4j installation directory: C:\develop\id-gui\id-gui\target\install4j
[ERROR] Missing install4j compiler executable: C:\develop\id-gui\id-gui\target\install4j\bin\install4jc.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since install4j is essentially a jar file

The maven plugin calls the native launcher `bin/install4jc`. Since there is no multi-platform tar.gz distribution with native launchers for all platforms for install4j, you have to install the appropriate archive on each platform where you want to use install4j.

Comment: Are the jar files platform-dependent, or is is just the `install4jc` starter? (In the latter case, it might at least theoretically be possible to directly call the jar file from the build process.)

Comment: The JAR files are platform-independent. What you can do is to prepare a .tar.gz file that includes the Unix launchers (they will work on macOS as well) and the Windows exe launchers from the bin directory. The maven plugin will call the rights ones automatically.

Comment: Nice, good to know. Sadly, I'm running out of my time budget and can't justify creating a self-contained multiplatform install4jc package, as I have already spent too much time on pushing JREs to our own Maven repo and integrating these into the build. When/if that works and EJ Tech decides to publish a multiplatform `install4jc` package, I'll be happy to contribute POM snippets that integrate it all. ... ... oh. Will the plugin accept a .tgz to launch install4jc from? oO

Comment: `Will the plugin accept a .tgz to launch install4jc from?` -> No, the install4j distribution has to be extracted.

Comment: Thanks, now I know how to proceed :-)